# Python GPSD Library Import Configuration

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpsd

I'm working on a writing a Python script that will interface with and pull GPSD data into an application. This obviously involves an external library.

I have set up my configuration as follows on the Raspberry Pi I am using to deploy the code:

```
sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients python-gps
```

I have a working test sample code that creates the gps listener and pulls in data. It looks something like this:

```
gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE)
while gpsp.running:
    gpsd.next()
```

It works great if I run it by calling the following command:

```
python test.py
```

But the code breaks due to an `ImportError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gps import *
ImportError: No module named gps
```

If I run it using:

```
python3 test.py
```

This makes sense to me because when I set up the project, I only included the libraries for the default Python (Python 2.7), not Python 3. [But `python3-gps` isn't a package](http://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages-list/item/87-raspbian-python), and the rest of my project demands Python 3, so I don't know what to do.

Would it be possible to copy the Python 2.7 build of the gps library into Python 3 without errors? What other libraries should I look at? Is there anyway around this error?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is a version make for version 3 -- see GitHub here...

https://github.com/tpoche/gps-python3

It advertises itself as a simple port to python 3....

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How do you "install" it? I have no idea which directory to copy the build over to or how to get it working properly.

Comment: I would (assuming you don't want to mess with virtualenvs) either install it in a subdir of your home directory or your project and add that subdir to your PYTHONPATH or install it in the source directory you are writing your project in.

Comment: Yeah I tried just putting it in my current working forlder, but I keep getting `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: Yep -- my guess is that the extra gps directory means you need to do a from gps.gps import GPSData

Answer (score 2):

The [GPS3 project found on github](https://github.com/wadda/gps3) is Python 2.7 to 3.4 compatible interface to the gpsd, yet doesn't import ancient cruft.

It is still alpha, but I would recommend it, at least for a poke and prod.

Comment: @JamesTaylor ...but to answer your python2.7 import problem it's really `from gps import gps`  or you could give gps3 a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pip3 installed use

```
pip3 install gps
```